# Using Regex span id and get contents help

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I need Regex this `<span id="more-186483">` Number 186483 is constantly changing, for each item is different.

Comment: So what do you need?  A list of all numbers following the string `"more-"` in a id attribute of any or all `span` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://site.com/file.html");

preg_match_all('%<span id="more-.*?">(.*?)</span>%i', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    echo $result[1][$i];
}
```

Comment: I owe you beer! Tnx for help!